# View specific mode in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to call a specific [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) view, not necessarily my default view, through a URL.

Something like `/my_calendar/?&mode=month`.

I searched the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/) and couldn't easily find anything that points to this.

I found [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1206518) though where they claim this is implemented in Drupal somehow. Not sure how to backport (if easily possible?).

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you just looking to have the url set the calendar view, or also the date?

Comment: Just the calendar view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on your calendar page, before your fullcalendar configuration you will need to add the following code. This will check if `$_GET['mode']` is set in the url and if it is, it will use a switch to make sure it is a valid value and then assign the JavaScript variable to that value and echo it to the page and if it is not set or if the value does not match it will assign the default value of month.

```
<script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['mode'])) {
    switch ($_GET['mode']) {
        case "month":
            echo "var mode = 'month';";
            break;
        case "agendaWeek":
            echo "var mode = 'agendaWeek';";
            break;
        default:
            echo "var mode = 'month';";
            break;
    }
} else {
    echo "var mode = 'month';";
}
?>
</script>
```

Then in your fullcalendar configuration you just need to set the following.

```
defaultView: mode,
```

Note: your IDE may say that mode is not defined if your fullcalendar configuration and fullcalendar page are separate. Thats fine as long as its defined on the calendar page before the script. With this code, a page like `calendar.php?mode=agendaWeek` will load the calendar with default view set to agendaWeek.